# adding class files to java package in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, package, black-box-testing

I have three .class files that I'm supposed to black-box test.  They are under a package named `one.two.three`.  I'm having difficulty accessing them.  I started a new java project in eclipse and created a package with the same name.  I then proceeded to add the three .class files to `bin/one/two/three`.  If I try using the classes Eclipse can't find them and I get compiler errors.  I'm using the appropriate package header. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: are they .class files or .java files?

Comment: hi ray, they're .class files i don't have access to the .java ones

Comment: you will need to get them into a jar and/or onto the build path somehow.

Comment: I tried adding them as external class files but doing so doesn't give me access to the enum inside the class.  I was told they have to be in the same package in order to work.  Thanks

Comment: you should get access if you put then in the right place. put them in foo/one/two/three/ and then add foo/ as a class folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming `bin/` is your output folder in the Eclipse project settings. Simply dropping the class files under `bin/one/two/three` will not work as eclipse will either delete them (on clean build) or just ignore these extra artifacts. Do as @Ray Tayek says- keep them in a different directory and edit project classpath and add this as class folder. This should work.